# Why my hamburger menu isn't displaying anywhere else except CodePen?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm working on a Frontend Mentor landing page project and I noticed that my hamburger menu wasn't showing so I tired it on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kiva-gordon/pen/QWqWEvR) and it was displaying clear as day.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-jc-sb {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-jc-c {
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-ai-c {
  align-content: center;
}
.header nav {
  padding: 24px;
}

.header__menu>span {
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #2d314d;
}

.header__menu>span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">

    <a href="/" class="header__logo">
      <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Jnx.svg" alt="Easybank">
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="header__menu">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[image: Localhost on Chrome]

[image: CodePen on Chrome]

Comment: Where are the `flex`, `flex-jc-sb`, and `flex-ai-c` classes coming from? What do they do? You probably have their source defined in your CodePen but not locally.

Comment: ''flex'' I use for  display: flex; ''flex-jc-sb'' is for justify: spacebetween; and ''ai-c'' is for align-content: center;. I just copied and pasted my code from VS Code to the pen to test it out and it worked there.

Comment: I've now added them to the snippet.

Comment: In your code snippet, when I run it, the hamburger appears exactly as it should on the right hand side. On looking, I think the only thing I would want to change is to add some kind of wrapper or container so that your logo and the hamburger are not right at the edges of the page. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: If it's displaying on codepen and not displaying inside your project, then some class is preventing it from being displayed in your code. Try to inspect element and see where is a problem.

Comment: It seems like your HTML file doesn't include your external CSS file.

Comment: @Tom I actually used SCSS I have 4 SCSS files one for globals, variables and header I imported those 3 into a style.scss and it complied to CSS and everything else seems to working fine and dandy except for the hamburger menu on my localhost.

Comment: @VeselinKontić I just checked my inspect element again and now it's telling me it failed to load the style.css but all the other CSS files are working.

Comment: Then just change route to css file. Not sure how else I can help you. You can check here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: @VeselinKontić I think I know the issue now my sass complier didn't compile some of my code to CSS, I just did everything again without the use of SCSS and it worked.